# A multiprocessor architecture and Ring 3

Tags: multithreading, x86, operating-system

```
void
sema_down (struct semaphore *sema) 
{
  old_level = intr_disable ();
  while (sema->value == 0) 
    {
      list_push_back (&sema->waiters, &thread_current ()->elem);
      thread_block ();
    }
  sema->value--;
  intr_set_level (old_level);
}
```

The above piece of code is a mechanim locking mutex in PintOS. PintOS is targeted for uniprocessor systems. Because of that fact it is sufficient to just disable interrupts. There is no possibility that the other will take a mutex.

So, let's consider a multiprocessor design:

```
void
sema_down (struct semaphore *sema) 
{
  old_level = intr_disable ();
  while (!lock cmpxchg(1,0)) // it is just pseudocode-idea
    {
      list_push_back (&sema->waiters, &thread_current ()->elem);
      thread_block ();
    }
  intr_set_level (old_level);
}
```

`old_level = intr_disable ();`. It turned off interrupts but it is crucial only in that CPU's context.

It can be a **prototype** of function acquiring mutex in MP architecture.  But, there is a problem with `list_push_back`. It must be also safe-multithreading. But, we cannot make it safe with a mutex because we are just implementing it now!

**The main question is:** 
Is it possible that two ( or more) CPUs are executing code on Ring 0 level ( kernel)?

And, subquestions that are dependent on the answer to the first one:

1. If not, there is no problem I described above. But- how it can be implemented?
2. If yes ( it seems impossible or very hard to realize), what about my above considerations ( It is just only example of potential problem). 
   Do we have to use `spinlocks` or `lock-free structures`?

Comment: Can you reduce the post to a single, clear, question? spinlocks and lock-free-programming are not bad if they are used to synchronise access to very short critical sections (like a one that updates a list) and cannot be avoided AFAIK.

Comment: @MargaretBloom, I edited to make it more clear what  I ask. Basically, it is single-question post. I didn't get rid of my subquestions because they are context-dependent and there is no point to put them in other post. ( I think so). I hope that it is more friendly for you.

Comment: I'm especially confused by this: "*Is it possible that two ( or more) CPUs are executing code on Ring 3 level ( kernel)*". Why you find surprising that different CPUs can execute the same code? And why there is a *kernel* next to *Ring 3* (which is user mode)?

Comment: @MargaretBloom, it is not surprising that CPUs can execute the same code. It is obvious- they can. I consider wheter they can execute code on Ring **0** ( I edited my post, I made a mistake earlier)  level simultaneously.

Comment: Since the IOAPIC can distribute external interrupts across a number of cores, that would require that each processor be able to operate code in ring 0 simultaneously. A ring 3 program on a processor might make a request to make a system call potentially switching the processor it is running on to ring 0. This can be done on all the cores. So yes, it is possible that there is code running at ring 0 on multiple cores simultaneously. If you have a multicore system that only uses a single core (default at bootup) there is no problem. You have to enable/bootstrap each core before using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in SMP multiple CPU can execute the same code, even at Ring 0.

Every CPU is symmetrical thus it can execute the same code path as the others (including kernel code), unless the software implements some sort of synchronization.

The Linux kernel also faced this problem, and initially implemented a not-so-good solution: [A Big Kernel Lock](http://www.makelinux.net/books/lkd2/ch09lev1sec8) that was acquired and released upon entering and exiting the kernel.

It was not a good solution because only one CPU at a time could execute the kernel code, but it was quick to implement and it was the equivalent of the item number one in you list.

A better solution is to use finer locks across the whole kernel.
Since is it the kernel that implements the sleeping locks like mutexes or  semaphores shown in your example, it cannot rely on those primitives themselves<sup>1</sup> and must use spinlocks or other, simpler, form of locking.

Luckily this is not a problem, a spinlock (and [its variants](https://events.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/slides/linuxcon-2014-locking-final.pdf)) is actually better than a mutex when there is a low contention or the critical path is really short (like updating a list).

You can take a look at [mutex_init](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/locking/mutex.c#L50) from Linux to see that a spinlock is used to synchronize the queue of waiting tasks.

```
 49 void
 50 __mutex_init(struct mutex *lock, const char *name, struct lock_class_key *key)
 51 {
 52         atomic_set(&lock->count, 1);


 53         spin_lock_init(&lock->wait_lock);


 54         INIT_LIST_HEAD(&lock->wait_list);
 55         mutex_clear_owner(lock);
 56 #ifdef CONFIG_MUTEX_SPIN_ON_OWNER
 57         osq_lock_init(&lock->osq);
 58 #endif
 59 
 60         debug_mutex_init(lock, name, key);
 61 }
```

So the answer to your second item is yes.

---

<sup>1</sup> You can't sleep while waiting to sleep while waiting for a lock.